# Mod_Rewrite: default value if cookie is not set

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I have the following rewrite rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=([^;]+)
RewriteRule .* $1/%{unescape:%1}/index.html [L]
```

I am wondering if there is a way to get a default value (like 'en') when the 'lang' cookie is not set (or empty). This way, the value of %1 would be the cookie's value or 'en'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a trick rule like this to get default value:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}##en lang=([^;]+)|##(en) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1/%{unescape:%1%2}/index.html [L]
```

Only one of the back-reference `%1` or `%2` will be populated due to use of regex alternation i.e. if `lang=([^;]+)` pattern matches cookies then `%1` will be set and `%2` will be empty. If `lang` cookie is not available then `%1` will be empty but `%2` will be set to `en`.

Comment: Thank it worked! I can't seem to find documentation on the "##" usage. Care to explain?

Comment: Oh that `##` can be just any arbitrary delimiter. It can very well be: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}:::en lang=([^;]+)|:::(en) [NC]` also.

Comment: Oh, it's brilliant!